# Getting False positives and False negatives relevant datasets of confusion matrix?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, confusion-matrix

I ran a `random classifier` on my text data and calculated a confusion matrix using the following code

```
#Plot the confusion matrix
plot_confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred, normalize=False,figsize=(15,8))
```

[image: See]

The above fig is what my confusion matrix looks like. Now, I want to see some datasets that belong to False positives and False negatives? In short, I want to see data which the classifier incorrectly labelled. How can I do this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have some object `x_test`, you could filter the rows where the prediction and the true label are different from one another.

```py
# Visualize observations that were incorrectly labeled
x_test[y_test != y_pred]
```

Comment: It does not work. IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).

Comment: Where did `X_test` come from? It's hard for me to tell since you only mentioned `y_test` and `y_pred`. I updated the answer, which will hopefully work now.

Comment: Oh, it won't work because `df` has more rows than `x_test`. I edited the answer. Can you try again please?

Comment: What about the false negatives? I think this for false positive, right ?

Comment: No. It's both - If `y_pred` is not equal to `y_test` then it includes cases when your model predicts 1 and it really is 0 as well as when it predicts 0 and it really is 1.

Comment: Just to confirm. I want to see data which the classifier incorrectly labelled. Both false positive and false negative. Does this code do this?

Comment: Yes. This code prints the observations that were incorrectly labeled (including false positives and false negatives).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238565/discussion-between-ankita-and-arturo-sbr).